# How do I get my Postman tests to pass using response body as the results?

Tags: javascript, postman, postman-collection-runner

I am attempting to write tests in Postman for the first time. I am using the `pm.test` method containing `pm.expect`.

Here is my test:

```
//contract details tests
pm.test("Contract data is correct", function() {
        pm.expect(pm.response.json().results.contractNb).to.equal("00002");
        pm.expect(pm.response.json().results.progSrvcNm).to.equal("009");
});
```

My response appears like so:

```
{
    "contractNb": "00002",
    "progSrvcNm": "009",
    "contractPartyNm": "testContract",
    "terms": 30,
    "startDt": "2018-01-01"
}
```

Comment: What is the full response body? Is `results` an array of objects?

Comment: I cannot include the full response data as it contains private customer data, but yes it is an array in the format

{
    "contractNb": "00002",
    "progSrvcNm": "009",
    "parameter": "value"
}

Comment: I found an answer from you Danny on this question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49586400/postman-test-scripts-inspecting-contents-of-response-json?rq=1

Thanks!

Comment: OK, you could of just masked all the sensitive pieces of information. It wasn't the data I was asking about, it was the structure of it. That answer is a bit old now and I bit there is a cleaner way of doing it. Can still help if you update the question with the Data.

Comment: Ok, I have edited the response body to reflect test data.

Comment: If that's the whole response body and nothing else, I would just remove the `results` part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your response body data - If you just remove the `.results` part of the `expect` statement, the check will pass.

```
pm.test("Contract data is correct", () => {
    pm.expect(pm.response.json().contractNb).to.equal("00002")
    pm.expect(pm.response.json().progSrvcNm).to.equal("009")
})
```

[image: Postman]

Comment: Thank you very much! I got the example using the results from the Postman example page. Going forward, should I ever use that?

Answer (score -1):

The correct code was as Danny Dainton posted.

```
pm.test('Contract details are correct for the passed in contract ID', () => {
    pm.expect(pm.response.json().contractNb).to.equal("00002");
    pm.expect(pm.response.json().progSrvcNm).to.equal("009");
});
```